# How do I use nested loops for finding matches in two-dimensional arrays?

Tags: c, loops, match

Looking for a bit of assistance with some assigned work. Rather than just correcting code, an explanation of what is happening if possible.

I am using a two-dimensional array to store criminal DNA profiles[10] in rows[3]. I now need to use a nested loop to check the suspects DNA profiles against the criminals DNA profiles. Here's the spec:

- Change the code for matching two profiles into the code for matching the suspect
  with each of the 3 criminals.
  Hint: Refer to Step 3. We need to similarly use a nested loop, with the outer loop, for `(int i = 0; i < sizeR; i++)`, for going through each of the criminals, and the inner loop, for
  `(int j = 0; j <sizeC; j++)`, for matching the corresponding chromosomes of the suspect
  and each criminal.

I understand that I need to adjust:

````
```bool match = true;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    if (suspect[i] != criminal[i])
        match = false;```
````

I just need to know how, and perhaps an explanation of what the code is doing? Here's the full code:

````
#include<stdbool.h>

int main () {
    int size = 10;
    float suspect[size]; //declare a suspect array
//declare a criminal array for more than one criminal.
    //(uses multiple rows, Row(R) Column (C)) 
    //3 sets of 10 input values  

    int sizeC = 10;          //values 
    int sizeR = 3;          //sets
    float criminals[sizeR][sizeC];


    //read 10 input values into the suspect array from the keyboard
    printf("Enter the 10 chromosomes of the suspect separated by spaces: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    scanf(" %f", &suspect[i]);
    // read multiple profiles of 10 values into criminal array from the keyboard
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeR; i++) {
        printf("Enter the 10 chromosomes of the %dth criminal: \n", i+1);
    // read 10 input values of a criminal into the criminals array from the keyboard
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeC; j++)
        scanf(" %f", &criminals[i][j])
    }

    //match two profiles
    bool match = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (suspect[i] != criminal[i])
            match = false;

    // display the results that match
    if (match)
    printf("The two profiles match! \n");
    else
    {
        printf("The two profiles don't match! \n");
        
    }
    

    return 0;

}```

Thanks in advance!
````

Comment: `suspect[i] != criminal[i]`, do you mean to say `criminals[i]` in this statment?

Comment: The task description tells you how to set up the nested loop: *the outer loop, for (int i = 0; i < sizeR; i++), for going through each of the criminals, and the inner loop, for (int j = 0; j <sizeC; j++)*. At a minimum you should code up a loop like that even if you don't know what to put in the body.

Comment: @csavvy yes that's a mistake

Comment: @kaylum yeah I see that, I am wondering where I place this and if I need to change my variables..and some guidance on what the loops are doing exactly.

Comment: You  replace the code where you currently have `//match two profiles`.

Comment: @kaylum thanks I'll give it my best shot and see where I can get.

Answer (score 0):

This part

```
//match two profiles
bool match = true;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    if (suspect[i] != criminal[i])
        match = false;
```

is wrong since you wanted to compare values from a two-d array `criminals` with a 1-d array `suspect`

`criminal[i]` points to your ith row

I assume your `size` is equal to `sizeR`

```
 for (int i = 0; i < sizeR; i++) 
 {
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeC; j++)
    {
         if( suspect[i] == criminals[i][j])
         {
            match = true;
            printf("suspect [%d] matches with criminals [%d][%d]\n", i, i, j);
         }
    }
 }
```